# Define a single trait out of multiple traits constrained by self-types

Tags: scala, scalatest, self-type

I have two `abstract class` that looks as follow:

```
abstract class BddAsyncSpec extends AsyncFeatureSpec
  with Matchers
  with GivenWhenThen
  with BeforeAndAfter
  with BeforeAndAfterAll

abstract class BddSpec extends FeatureSpec
  with Matchers
  with GivenWhenThen
  with BeforeAndAfter
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
```

as you can see, the mixin part looks the same. My question is, how to abstract the mixin part, that when I add more trait, then it applies for `BddAsyncSpec` and `BddSpec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
trait MyTraits extends Matchers
  with GivenWhenThen with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll { this: Suite with Informing => }

abstract class BddAsyncSpec extends AsyncFeatureSpec with MyTraits
abstract class BddSpec extends FeatureSpec with MyTraits
```

where we use [self-type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html)

```
this: Suite with Informing =>
```

because, for example, `GivenWhenThen` requires `Informing`

```
trait GivenWhenThen { this: Informing =>
```

and `BeforeAndAfter` and `BeforeAndAfterAll` require `Suite`

```
trait BeforeAndAfter extends SuiteMixin { this: Suite =>
```

Self-types are a way of specifying what the trait requires in order to be mixed-in.

Answer (score 0):

With another trait that is a set of common traits?

```
trait T1; trait T2
trait Common extends T1 with T2
abstract class BaseA; abstract class BaseB;
abstract class A extends BaseA with Common
abstract class B extends BaseB with Common
```